# cross thread problem

Tags: c#, data-binding, multithreading

I have one button with following code

```
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        DataTable table = Finish(txtTest.Text);
        //dgwTest.DataSource = table

    }).Start();
```

and I would like to set datagridview data source but I get an "cross thread" exception. Anyone know how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string source = txtTest.Text;

```
new Thread(() =>
{
      DataTable table = Finish(source);
      dgwTest.Invoke ((Action) (() => dgwTest.DataSource = table));
}).Start();
```

Comment: Hmm I get compiler error after using this code Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Jack - I've just edited @agent-j's code - adding brackets around the lamba to allow the cast to work. Should work for you now.

Comment: @David... Thanks.  Maybe I should just use delegate syntax... Sometimes it's simpler.  `.Invoke ((Action)delegate {MessageBox.Show("");});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Invoke method on the `DataGridView`

```
private delegate void SetDGVValueDelegate(DataTable table);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() =>    {        
        DataTable table = Finish(txtTest.Text);

        SetDGVValue(table);

    }).Start();

}

private void SetDGVValue(DataTable table) 
{ 
    if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired) 
    { 
        dataGridView1.Invoke(new SetDGVValueDelegate(SetDGVValue), table); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code but my data grid view never gets updated :(

Comment: @Jack What happens if you call the method SetDGVValue from the main ui thread? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger, checking that the DataTable is correctly populated?

Comment: DataTable is correctly populated if I run this code without using new Thread() ... it work fine except the fact that whole program becomes unresponsive

Comment: @Jack - odd, in my test code this works fine. If you try the thread example, and set a breakpoint, what to you see happen in the SetGDVValue method? And as an aside, any reason why you aren't using a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: I dont know much about Threading (read: I dont know anything), I have just read few tutorials on the web to get this working. I have tried to used background worker but as I dont have any experience with it I have just run into even more problems. I'll try to crate a new project and see what's going on if it works for you then I'm doing something wrong. Thxx for help :)

Comment: I have somehow removed Start(), now it works. I have accepted previous answer as it's one line code but, once again thanks